# Count total results of a number within a certain range using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The goal of the project is to check the total character count of a textarea field and compare the conversion rate against historical data.  Simply: Person X enters 300 characters, and I want to see the conversion rate of previous people who entered between 260 and 340 characters.

Here's a working MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS total_count, 
  SUM(converted) AS total_converted, 
  (SUM(converted) / count(*)) * 100 AS conversion_rate, text_length
FROM my_table WHERE text_length IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY text_length div 40
```

This works fine for lower numbers, but at a certain point (like over 400 characters), I'd like to just lump them all together. Is there a way to check if the 'text_length' is over a certain value and then just COUNT everything above it?

Also, if anyone has any suggestions for a better overall approach, I'd be happy to try that, too.
Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything wrong with doing two queries, one excluding texts longer than 400 characters, and the other one returning SUM(converted/text_length)/COUNT(*) for all length>400?

Comment: To Borealid's comment, you could combine the results of two queries using UNION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using UNION, you could do this:

```
(SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS total_count, 
  SUM(converted) AS total_converted, 
  (SUM(converted) / count(*)) * 100 AS conversion_rate, text_length
FROM my_table
WHERE text_length <= 400
GROUP BY text_length div 40)
UNION
(SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS total_count, 
  SUM(converted) AS total_converted, 
  (SUM(converted) / count(*)) * 100 AS conversion_rate, 401 AS text_length
FROM my_table
WHERE text_length > 400)
```

Notice that I've also removed the `WHERE text_length IS NOT NULL` which is no longer needed. Your text_lengths that are greater than 400 will be grouped as text_length 401.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
GROUP BY (text_length > 400), CAST((text_length / 40) AS INTEGER)
```

That would make anything with 401+ characters group together into a single group, and then anything 400 or less get grouped by the `40` char divisions.

Comment: Thanks. Doing a quick check, the CAST is throwing a syntax error, but I'll try to debug later.  I'm not too familiar with CAST() so I need to read up.